# Using a class method as an argument to a function

Tags: python, function, oop, functional-programming

I want to pass an class method as an argument to a function which applies the method to an instance. I wrote a simplified example of my problem down, which does not work. Is there a way to do this in python?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = [1,2,3]
        
    def combine(self) -> int:
        return sum(self.values)
    
    def return_zero(self) -> int:
        return 0
    

def apply_func(instance, func):
    return instance.func()


print(apply_func(A(), A.combine))

> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
def apply_func(instance, func):
    return instance.func()
```

you should do:

```
def apply_func(instance, func):
    return func(instance)
```

Remember the method is defined as `def combine(self)` - by calling `func(instance)`, the `instance` simply becomes that `self`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9dC8IgFIbv/RXnUsFGtZsICvY7IsTMkeDORF2w/rxNHGu76b07H88Drxvjq8f65HxKysoQoDkTmPLULQhh0EQhaNC2ZWWfk8fqLe2gA1zgduBHXt@X64KrvnsY1IWG3RUMxp/E6zh4hDB0dOVjZKMoT@Kjff9fsy8cyZB0zo6iHVBRgyFKVJpDHucKM7J5YIQQ5yczXdENZRyaau7BWEpf)

Comment: Wow I did not know about this behaviour either! Thats the solution I intended to write. Thanks for the clearance.:)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def apply_func(instance, func):
    fn = getattr(instance, func)
    return fn()


print(apply_func(A(), 'combine'))
```

Out:

```
6
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about `getattr`, it works!

Comment: Doesn't really "pass an class method", though, just its name.